# How to stitch UAV images using pix4D software?

Tags: image-stitching, photogrammetry

I just want to register UAV images side by side using pix4D software, but the problem is I don't have any GCPs. How do I get a mosaic where all the images are stitched properly?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you describe your issue in more detail, please? E.g. by adding code, commands or screen shots which describe your problem. Is your question related to programming? Please have also a look to the Help Center, especially for [asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [minimal examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Images with Pix4d are typically referenced with geo-information (data tagged from INS/GPS and IMU). If this is not the case, there is no way for Pix4d to know where your images are in space.
An alternative to geo-referenced images is to create Manual Tie Points. This is a tedious process and has an effect on accuracy + image distortion. Check out Pix4D tutorials on Youtube or Pix4d/FAQ's for how to tag your images with MTP's.
Hope that helps & good luck.